# passing the parameter to click function of jquery mobile simple dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, modal-dialog

I have the following jquery code

```
function deleteAppointment(confirmationNumber)
{
//        alert(confirmationNumber);
     $('#left').simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'bool',
        'prompt' : 'Confirm Delete',
        'useModal': true,
        'buttons' : {
          'OK': {
            click:function () {
//                    alert(confirmationNumber);
                var link;       
                link = ROOT_URL+'Queue/cancelreservation/confirmnumber/'+confirmationNumber;        
                $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        renderAgain();
                        addRightPane();
                        $(APPOINTMENT_LIST_CLASS).animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        });

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        /*@TODO : What if the ajax request fails */
                    }
                });
            }

          },
          'Cancel': {
            click: function () {
              $('#dialogoutput').text('Cancel');
            },
            icon: "delete",
            theme: "c"
          }
        }

    });             
}
```

the problem is that confirmation number I pass to the delete appointment function is only passed for the first time and is not updated the next time. It holds the value of old confirmation number so I figured out that I have to pass the confirmation number to the click function. Can any one help me on how to do that ? or what I am missing here ?

Comment: Conformation number is it stored in some html param or some id of element ?

Comment: it is passed here from another function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few weeks more experience in jquerymobile I find more elegant and right way to fix this issue

just use a property of simple dialog

```
'cleanOnClose' : true
```

this will fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your delete button is something like this

```
<a class="deleteappoinment" href="javascript:void(0);" id="12">Delete</a> //here 12 is an example of conformation id, change it accordingly

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.deleteappoinment').click(function(){

            deleteAppointment($(this).attr('id'));

      });
    });

function deleteAppointment(confirmationNumber){
 //code
}
```

Comment: well its like this.. but the problem is in the code part. the confirmation number doesnt update every time the deleteappointment function us called.

Comment: the alert above the dialog gives the value i needed. while the alert inside click function of ok button retains its old value

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to do same thing like you have done, one function that will refill a simple dialog but the problem is that onclick has to be unbind and bind again but I didn't know how.I just make a work around and used a global variable to pass a paramater

this should do a trick... if somebody knows how to rebind events please let us know

```
var selected;

 function deleteAppointment(confirmationNumber)
{
selected = confirmationNumber;
//        alert(confirmationNumber);
     $('#left').simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'bool',
        'prompt' : 'Confirm Delete',
        'useModal': true,
        'buttons' : {
          'OK': {
            click:function () {
//                    alert(selected );
                var link;       
                link = ROOT_URL+'Queue/cancelreservation/confirmnumber/'+selected ;        
                $.ajax({
                    url: link,
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data){
                        renderAgain();
                        addRightPane();
                        $(APPOINTMENT_LIST_CLASS).animate({
                            scrollTop: 0
                        });

                    },
                    error: function(){
                        /*@TODO : What if the ajax request fails */
                    }
                });
            }

          },
          'Cancel': {
            click: function () {
              $('#dialogoutput').text('Cancel');
            },
            icon: "delete",
            theme: "c"
          }
        }

    });             
}
```

Comment: actually I went with this solution as well i.e. using the global variable.